How to properly rename Hangfire job?
I use Hangfire for running a set of recurrent jobs. Sometimes I wanted to rename these jobs. However, it is not clear how to do that.
E.g. I have the code:
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Old Name", () => SomeJob(), "Cron");

If I wanted to rename it I have to do the following:
RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("Old Name");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("New Name", () => SomeJob(), "Cron");

but in this case, the history of jobs will be lost.
Maybe there is a better way to rename the job?

The method RemoveIfExists properly removes the Hangfire job. I don't know about renaming, but what about disabling the job, is it sufficient for you?

@T.Dominik sorry for the confusion, I wrongly wrote the title of the question. I wanted to rename the job, not remove it.

Hangfire does not expose any API that will help you with that - not that I know of. But you can try it manually via SQL scripts.
Something like this:
Update [HangFire].[Set] SET [Value] = 'Your_new_JobName' where [Value] = 'Your_Old_job_name'

AND
Update [Hangfire].[Hash] SET [Key] = 'recurring-job:Your_new_JobName' where [Key]= 'recurring-job:Your_Old_job_name'

This should be enough to update recuring job name and keep history.

I'm just curious because I'm also using Hangfire, is it safe to do this in production apps? Because the internal behaviors of Hangfire may change (different version also) or the job name may be used elsewhere.

@T.Dominik Yes I think its pretty safe - only places where job name is mentioned is here - all the other tables with metadata are using jobid.
